# Comparing strengths of Hydrogen Bonds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, hydrogen-bond

What kind of a bond is the Hydrogen bond? Is it electrostatic forces of attraction or more like a partial coordinate bond? 
What pair of atoms would provide us the strongest Hydrogen bond? If we consider electrostatic forces then HF and HF should be strongest. But how about HF and NH2?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/is-hydrogen-bonding-a-type-of-dipole-dipole-interaction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifluoride