# The reason for Hydrogen bonding

Tags: bond, hydrogen-bond

Why does hydrogen bonding take place? Is there any kind of electron donation? Or does something like an ionic bond take place?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-does-it-really-need-fluorine-oxygen-or-n

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/is-hydrogen-bonding-a-type-of-dipole-dipole-interaction